# SSL proxy for two applications on same domain (one application without context path)

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I have 2 applications running on separate tomcat on the same server machine

application 1 : www.example.com 
application 2 : www.example.com/app

I have made the configuration and SSL works for application 1 but not for application 2.

When I try to go to https:www.example.com/app , i get a page not found exception

> httpd.conf

```
ServerName example.com

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

SSLEngine               On

SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain_com_with_chain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/mydomain_com.key

ProxyPass               /       http://myserver:8081/
ProxyPassReverse        /       http://myserver:8081/

ProxyPass               /app       http://myserver:8082/app
ProxyPassReverse        /app       http://myserver:8082/app
```

The server.xml configuration is correct with the connector having proxy parameters

```
 <Connector port="8081"
               maxThreads="150"
               minSpareThreads="25"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               enableLookups="false"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
               acceptCount="100"
               disableUploadTimeout="true"
               scheme="https"
               proxyName="example.com"
               proxyPort="443"
               secure="true"/>
```

Can someone please point out the problem here . I suspect it is because application 1 does not have a context path. However, I cannot have a context path for my application 1.
Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: What's is your apache version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really running both tomcats on 8081 and 8082 (because you're only giving one Connector configuration), here's an excerpt from the [mod_proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) (emphasis mine):

> Ordering ProxyPass Directives
>
> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch **rules are checked in the
>   order of configuration**. The first rule that matches wins. So usually
>   you should **sort conflicting ProxyPass rules starting with the longest
>   URLs first**. Otherwise, later rules for longer URLS will be hidden by
>   any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL. Note that
>   there is some relation with worker sharing. In contrast, only one
>   ProxyPass directive can be placed in a Location block, and the most
>   specific location will take precedence.

This means that it should be enough to reorder

```
ProxyPass               /app       http://myserver:8082/app
ProxyPassReverse        /app       http://myserver:8082/app

ProxyPass               /       http://myserver:8081/
ProxyPassReverse        /       http://myserver:8081/
```

In addition, you might want to look at Joao Vitorino's answer for changing the second argument to ProxyPassReverse - I'm typically not using ProxyPass and its related options, so I can't tell from the top of my head.

The culprit for the missing match seems to be that the first ProxyPass, covering `/`, wins over the second for `/app`

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks this helps with the redirection however, the resources like images and javascripts are not downloaded and I get a 404 for these resources when I see them in the browser console. Can you please point me to what I am missing . Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest to validate the exact URLs, monitor Apache's and Tomcat's logs closely to see where they're downloaded from. I don't expect a lot of caching with 404 errors, but better be safe than sorry: Try force-reload as well.

Comment: i tried to force reload and the links are correct. Could this be a file system permission issue ? I will check the logs as well.

Comment: I just realized my configuration is missing the below lines.can this be a reason. I have requested the server team for this changes , i hope this helps.
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

Comment: *Can* this be a reason? Sure. In your question you state that this is part of your configuration - what is it? Is it in or not?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your proxypass

You have

```
ProxyPass               /       http://myserver:8081/
ProxyPassReverse        /       http://myserver:8081/

ProxyPass               /app       http://myserver:8082/app
ProxyPassReverse        /app       http://myserver:8082/app
```

Should be

```
ProxyPass               /       http://myserver:8081/
ProxyPassReverse        /       https://www.example.com/

ProxyPass               /app       http://myserver:8081/app
ProxyPassReverse        /app       https://www.example.com/app
```

Unless you have a port offset, there is no reason to call port 8082

[Apache ProxyPass Doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)